# What is the implied noun in "empanada"?

Tags: comida, sustantivos

I love empanadas. As I was eating one today, I guessed that "empanada" must mean something like "breaded". A quick web search made me feel inordinately proud of my guess. But I can't yet find a name for the thing that's been breaded. It must be a feminine, of course. "Torta" seems wrong.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

EDIT: This question may be a duplicate of [this one](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/empanada-emparedado-and-their-genders). The suggestion there is that "carne" is the implied word.

Comment: It's a good question. Whatever it is, it must refer to the stuffing. "Torta" wouldn't fit that, as it is also made of cereal, and referring to the whole.

Comment: What makes you think there is an implied noun?  There is no implied noun in "enchilada", or "frito", which are all the same sorts of words. They translate literally to English as "En-chilied thing," "fried thing" or, in your case, "breaded thing."

Comment: I think there's an implied noun because "hand me that enchilied/fried/breaded" makes little sense out of context. Of course there is a context for the words now, but at some point in their history they were brand-new. At that time, to refer to "the breaded" would have been, uh, less clear. Also, the words you mention have different genders, which suggests that they have different referents. Anyway, if "empanada" translates literally into "breaded thing", then perhaps "thing" is the implied noun - la cosa empanada. It doesn't explain "frito", but it's something.

Comment: It's "carne". Carne empanada -> empanada.

Comment: @angus: Carne empanada looks to be what I might call chicken-fried steak - delicious, but not the same thing. :)

Comment: @Tony: That's now. Now, for the pastry you don't use "x empanado" anymore, but "empanada de x"; so the expression "x empanado" was taken over by the breaded dishes.

Comment: My point is that "Hand me that enchilied/fried/breaded" *does* make perfect sense in Spanish. We do the exact same thing in English by pluralizing an adjective.  Examples: Fries, sugaries, sweeties, icies, smooties.  There is no implied noun.  "Sugaries" can be anything that is sugary... "Sugery ones."

Comment: @angus: So a) "carne empanada" was the original term, b) it got shortened (heh) to just "empanada", and c) now "carne empanada" means something else?

Comment: There are many kind of empanada. While the meat one is the most common in some countries it is not so for others.

Answer (score 3):

There is an implied action: **empanar**. It means, according to DRAE,

> empanar.
>   1. tr. Encerrar **algo** en masa o pan para cocerlo en el horno.

So there you are. Indeed the implied noun is (drums)... **algo**, i.e. whatever fits inside the *bread*. It could be meat. But there's no *fixed* implied known. But the fact that the bread should be stuffed leads to the participle of *empanar*, namely *empanada*.

Comment: I mean what is the thing that's being breaded. "Pan empanado" seems a bit much. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no implied noun, other than possibly the ambiguous "one" or "thing," as in:

> Breaded one

or

> Breaded thing

The exact same thing happens in English (and probably every other language) when we use an adjective form in the place of a noun to describe something by its primary characteristic.

Some obvious examples from Spanish, and their literal English translations, are:

- Enchiladas -- En-chillied ones/things
- Fritos -- Fried ones/things -- or "fries"
- Helados -- Frozen ones/things -- Anything frozen (ice cream, popcicles)

Some obvious ones in English:

- Fries -- Anything fried (often French Fried potatoes, but not always)
- Sweets / Sweeties -- Anything sweet: candy, ice cream, etc
- Sugaries -- Anything sugary: candy, cookies, deserts, etc

Comment: I don't know of "fries" being used for anything but potatoes, and I've never heard "sweetie" or "sugary" used at all. We use adjectives and participles for people all the time - only the lonely, we are the chosen - but it's pretty clear that the word "people" is implied there. But I think my main objection is that the Spanish participles-as-nouns that you mention have different genders. All of that said, you may be right. Can you point me to some other analyses that confirm your idea? Thanks.

Comment: @Tony: I'm not sure why "sweeties" came to mind first... "sweets" would be the more common word, and I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Flimzy - I agree with you that there is no *explicit* noun being modified.  It is too much of a leap, though, to say that there's no *implicit* noun being modified.

Answer (score 1):

I support the answer by @c.p. but would like to clarify a couple things.

1. What is an *empanada*?  Naturally, there is regional variation!  Here is one possible configuration:

   [image: empanada]

   The *empanada* pictured is similar to what in English can be called a *hand pie* or *half moon pie*.  (I'd add *turnover* to this list if turnovers weren't usually triangular shaped.)

   It might be sweet or savory (or conceivably a combination, e.g. empanada de queso).

   It is often made with wheat flour but other types of starch are also possible, e.g. plantain.

   It may be fried or baked.

   OP appears to want to know, also (judging by the comment below c.p.'s answers), what to call the theme of the particular *empanada*, i.e. how to refer to the filling.  As @eSedano pointed out in a self-deleted answer, it would be called, at least in Mexico:

   **relleno**

   But note that the theme ingredient of the empanada can be either a discrete filling, added during the shaping phase, or it can be incorporated into the short dough during the initial mixing of the dough.
2. The *empanada* I am most familiar with (eastern central Mexico) is based on a **short pastry** or **shortcrust pastry**.  It's no longer based, in this day and age, on *bread* or *pan* as we now use these terms.  [Oxford defines *shortcrust pastry*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shortcrust) as "crumbly pastry made with flour, fat, and a little water, typically used for pies [...] and tarts."

   However, there are recipes in which the oil doesn't appear as an initial ingredient, and doesn't get incorporated into the *empanada* until the deep frying.

Answer (score 0):

It can be very different pie depending on the country.

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empanada

> An empanada (Spanish pronunciation: [empaˈnaða]; also called pastel in
>   Brazilian Portuguese and pate in Haitian Creole) is a stuffed bread or
>   pastry baked or fried in many countries in Southern Europe, Latin
>   America, the Southwestern United States, and parts of Southeast Asia.
>   **The name comes from the Galician, Portuguese, and Spanish verb
>   empanar, meaning to wrap or coat in bread.**
>
> Empanadas are made by folding dough or bread around stuffing, which
>   usually consists of a variety of meat, cheese, huitlacoche, vegetables
>   or fruits, among others.

Answer (score 0):

In this case we are in front of a word that can work as a noun and as an adjective.

> carne empanada --> Here empanada is an adjective of carne
>
> He hecho empanada, ¿de qué? empanada de carne --> Here empanada is a noun

Usually the genre of the word could confound people. If we use, for example "atún" with empanada we get:

> atún empanado --> again working as an adjective, it gets the genre of the noun.
>
> He hecho empanada, ¿de qué? empanada de atún --> Here is a noun, and it's genre stays the same

This is because empanada can be a noun, but empanado not, it's always an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implied noun.

It is the same as "sandwich" in english:

```
I am going to buy a tuna sandwich

Me voy a comprar una empanada de jamon y queso
```

So, if a sandwich is "anything between two slices of bread" an empanada is "anything wrapped in dough and baked or fried"

Wikipedia states that empanadas descend from middle eastern samosas, but the oldest european empanadas, the galician ones, are pies, very much similar to the ones known in the anglo-saxon world

Comment: I would say it´s the same as "pasty" in english. A sandwich is "bocadillo" in a roll/stick loaf. Arouind the tourist areas you also find "sandwich" used when it is made with two slices of bread.

Comment: You didn't get the comparison. It is on word uage, not meaning

Comment: Sure there is a noun, pan.

Comment: Rafa, you did not understand the question in the slightes it seems. The OP asks what breaded is referred to, as it does not make mush sense translated litteraly in English. So, the OP wants to know what is that is breaded, not not why the word is derived from bread

Comment: Bruno - you´re right, I misread your post

Answer (score 0):

An old word for what there is inside the bread is [**companaje**](http://dle.rae.es/companaje) or [**compango**](http://dle.rae.es/compango).

But I've never heard it in the wild, so it is likely that even a native will not understand it.

Comment: Compango = companaje es  Comida fiambre que se toma con pan, y a veces se reduce a queso o cebolla. - - **que se toma con pan** no necesariamente indica que esté entre dos panes,; puede ser **que se toma acompañado con pan**.

Answer (score -1):

The word for `breaded` is `empanizado` or `empanado`

Meaning that the verbs `empanizar` and `empanar` each mean `to bread`

Whoever mentioned the translation `breaded thing` was the most accurate, because that's exactly what it is.  The em- preffix suggests that something is inside.

However, Spanish and Latin American culture has two kinds of breads,  `de harina` and `de masa`.
If the bread you are using to `empanar` something is masa, then the verb goes from being `to bread` to `to cook/bake inside bread`

Rather, `to cook inside pastry`

> But I can't yet find a name for the thing that's been breaded. It must
>   be a feminine, of course.

I can't say that I know exactly what the subject of empanada is, but like you said, it is feminine, so it must either be `masa`, `harina`, or `fruta` that is the "implied subject".

Comment: http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/empanado

Comment: http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/empanada - here it is translated as pie.